# Display many images in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a number of logos that I want to display in my form. 
The thing is that in each row there are only 3 images whereas there is space for a couple of images more.

For example I have 10 images to display. 
Current output is 3 images on first row, 3 images on second row, 4 images on last row.
I want 5 on first and 5 on second.

This is the css of the logo area :

```
.logos{
width:400px;
display:block;
margin-top:3px;
margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

Comment: We need way more info than this. Show some screenshots and code, dimension of images etc. Preferably even a test setup in a fiddle.

Comment: could you please post more code?  how you have incorporated the image alignment etc., ?

Comment: For a question like this, I think you didn't try enough. Without trying you will learn nothing.

Comment: It maybe caused by the default styling on your browser(s). Try adding `padding: 0;` and `margin: 3px 0;` to your selector(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. Like using the `float: left;` attribute. I would give you a fiddle, but I can't see your HTML code and I don't want give you the code, before I truly know you are going to learn from this.

You can have the fish, but it is better to obtain a rod.